# How I can combine Google maps API and others (maps.andex.ru or Bing) in one application

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, bing-maps

There are many services, where user can switch API: gpsies.com, gdeetotdom.ru/map etc. How I can develop common map factory? Have anybody some tutorials or examples?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at OpenLayers javascript library.  They have a framework for building maps applications with many different sources of data.